# Package references with mixed .csproj formats in a solution

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, upgrade, csproj

I am currently preparing our backend solution to be ported to .Net Core. There are still some major things to be done, before we can do that fully. As a first step I am upgrading all the projects from .Net Framework 4.5.2 to 4.6.1 so we can migrate our external packages to .Net Standard 2.0.

In doing so, I also switched to the new .csproj structure for all projects, except for the web-api (my understanding is that is it not possible yet, and also if it were, we are making heavy use of custom msbuild steps which I don't want to migrate/reimplement at this point in time).

The problem I run into now is colliding versions of nuget packages, since the projects using the new .csproj only have transitive package references (and hence no explicit versions) yet the api project has explicit versions for the packages. The transitive ones ofter resolve to a different version.

How can I handle this situation? I have spent countless hours trying to up/-downgrade existing packages to get it all to match up, but that can't be the way.

Comment: My team also spent countless hours on this, and we surrendered and went back to the old style. What I want to warn against is 4.6.1 - the System.Net.Http reference is fundamentally broken, for many of the same dependency problems. Look to 4.7.1 or 4.7.2

Comment: @DavidJetter thanks for you comment. I was fearing that that might be the best course of action :( Have you found any other experiences/material/documentation about this problem online? I'd be glad for any reference.